# PHP Submit Inputs Foreach() ID

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to submit a form that contains a schedule for each user ID. So far it looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbtable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $name_info = "SELECT udidId, name FROM udid";
    $name_result = $conn->query($name_info);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $udidId = $row["udidId"];
            echo "<label for='hours' class='schedule'><strong>I want <span>".$row["name"]."</span>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='udidId' class='hidden' value='".$row["udidId"]."' />";
            echo " to be <br />allowed out between <input type='text' name='outAllowedStartHour' placeholder='8' value='" . $row["outAllowedStartHour"] . "'> - <input type='text' name='outAllowedEndHour' placeholder='8' value='" . $row["outAllowedEndHour"] . "'><br />allowed in between <div class='padd_left'></div><input type='text' name='inAllowedStartHour' placeholder='8' value='" . $row["inAllowedStartHour"] . "'> - <input type='text' name='inAllowedEndHour' placeholder='8' value='" . $row["inAllowedEndHour"] . "'></strong></label>";
        }
}    


if(isset($_POST["update_schedule"])) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value' <br />"; 
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              foreach($value as $x => $x_value) {
                echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
                echo "<br>";
                $update_pets = "UPDATE v_spottData SET $x_value = $x_value WHERE udidId = $x";
$conn->execute($update_pets);
              }
            }
        }
```

However is only updating inputs from the last ID in the database, and is not updating the input values at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: put your $conn->query($update_pets); after the $update_pets string.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Stitch, but that didn't appear to solve anything

Comment: i'm not sure what framework you are using but try to change $conn->query to $conn->execute.

Comment: can you update your post with my suggestion included?

Comment: It's giving the same result :/

Comment: "SET $x_value = $x_value" the other $x_value should be the column name i believe?

Comment: Don't put user data directly in SQL, use parameterized queries in prepared statements. php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php You need to `prepare` to `execute`. `$x_value` is the column and value? If so first instance should in in backticks, second in quotes.

Comment: @chris85 could you give me an example?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: I don't have enough information to give an example is `$x_value = $x_value` correct? It'd seem like the column name wouldn't vary that much..

Comment: @chris85 There are 4 columns: outAllowedStartHour, outAllowedEndHour, inAllowedStartHour and inAllowedEndHour.

Comment: A number, anywhere from 0-24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really silly, but for anyone else dealing with the issue, my solution was simple.

Try putting the PHP to handle the form submission at the top of your document, instead of at the bottom. Everything worked fine once I moved it up!

Thank you for all of your help everyone, especially @chris85!

Comment: The code in the question won't execute even if moved at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Execute` doesn't `execute` a query, it executes a prepared statement. You need to use `prepare` to prepare the query.
2. Prepared statements should use placeholders. The quoting/escaping will be handled by the driver.
3. Note columns can't be bound/placeheld.
4. Your current query is trying to update a column with the same value, that can't be right. Change `$updating_column` below to whatever column you are trying to update.

---

```
$columns = array('outAllowedStartHour', 'outAllowedEndHour', 'inAllowedStartHour', 'inAllowedEndHour'); // whitelist columns
if(in_array($updating_column, $columns)) {
     $update_pets = "UPDATE v_spottData SET `$updating_column` = ? WHERE udidId = ?";
     $stmt = $con->prepare($update_pets);
     $stmt->bind_param("ii", $x_value, $x);
     $stmt->execute();
} else {
     echo 'Using a Not Allowed Column';
}
```

You can read more about prepared statements here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: Thank you @chris85, how would I extract the value for the updating column and udidId in this case?

Comment: They should be the `$x_value, $x`.

Comment: like so? `$update_pets = "UPDATE v_spottData SET '$updating_column' = $x_value WHERE udidId = $x";`

Comment: What is wrong with the answer? Quotes aren't for columns/tables they are for strings. Variables shouldn't be in your query, or at least should be whitelist checked.

Comment: If I copy your answer as-is, the 'Using a Not Allowed Column' error is echoed.

Comment: `$updating_column` needs to be the column you are trying to insert into. It needs to be one of 4 values, `'outAllowedStartHour', 'outAllowedEndHour', 'inAllowedStartHour', 'inAllowedEndHour'`.

Comment: Yes, didn't read the supplied link, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.?

Comment: @ColoursB What is the status here?